# PHP session lost sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a php script that manages a form with many multiple choice questions. I save all the questions, answers and given answer in a session variable and at the end I save the variable in the DB. The script works fine, but sometimes, when I go the the next question, all the session are lost. I could not find a pattern and the datas seams ok.
I try to post the important parts of my code (I apologize for the length, but I have no idea where the problem is).

The controller:

```
class Teoria
{

    private $completeForm;
    private $categoryName;
    private $actualExercise;
    private $sequenceNumber;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $um = new UserModel();
        $user = $um->getUserByEmail($_SESSION[SESSION_EMAIL]);
        $_SESSION['userData'] = $user['firstname']." ".$user['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['language_id'] = $user['language_id'];

    }


    public function exam($id = null){
        $_SESSION['exerciseTipology'] = "exam";
      
        if(!$id){
            $this->generateEmptyExam();
        }
       
        header("location: " . URL . "teoria/callQuestion/1");
        exit();
    }


    public function addStudentAnswerAndCalculateErrorsAjax(){
        $this->addStudentAnswer();
        $this->calculateErrors();

    }

    function addStudentAnswer(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['completeForm'])) {
            $this->completeForm = $_SESSION['completeForm'];
            $sequenceNumber = $_POST['sequenceNumber'];
            $questionPosition = $_POST['questionPosition'];
            $checked = $_POST['checked'];
            $this->completeForm[$sequenceNumber]['answers'][$questionPosition]['checked'] = $checked;

            $_SESSION['completeForm'] = $this->completeForm;
        }
    }

    public function callQuestion($sequenceNumber){
        $this->sequenceNumber = $sequenceNumber;
        if(isset($_SESSION['completeForm'])) {
            $this->completeForm = $_SESSION['completeForm'];

            if ($this->sequenceNumber == 0) {
                $this->sequenceNumber = count($this->completeForm);
            }
            if ($this->sequenceNumber > count($this->completeForm)) {
                $this->sequenceNumber = 1;
            }

            $this->actualExercise = $this->completeForm[$this->sequenceNumber];

            require 'application/views/_template/header.php';
            require 'application/views/_template/navbar.php';
            require 'application/views/theory/exercise.php';
            echo '<script src="js/timer.js"></script>';

            require 'application/views/_template/footer.php';
        }
    }

 
    public function homeExam()
    {
        MSession::checkTheory();
        $tm = new TheoryModel();
        $exams = $tm->getExamsByUserAndCategory($_SESSION[SESSION_EMAIL],$_SESSION['categoryName']);

        require_once 'application/views/_template/header.php';
        require_once 'application/views/_template/navbar.php';
        require_once 'application/views/theory/homeExam.php';
        require_once 'application/views/_template/footer.php';
    }


    public function generateEmptyExam(): void
    {
        $tm = new TheoryModel();
        $categoryName = $_SESSION['categoryName'];
        $categoryId = $tm->getCategoryByName($categoryName)['id'];
        $categoryQuestions = $tm->getRandomQuestionByCategoryAndLanguage($categoryId,$_SESSION['language_id']);
        if ($categoryQuestions) {
            $this->completeForm = array();
            $singleQuestion = array();
            $answers = array();
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($categoryQuestions as $question) {
                $singleQuestion['question'] = $tm->getQuestionById($question['theory_question_id']);
                $singleQuestion['answers'] = $tm->getAnswersByQuestionId($singleQuestion['question']['id']);

                for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($singleQuestion['answers']); $ii++) {
                    $singleQuestion['answers'][$ii]['checked'] = "false";
                }

                $singleQuestion['errors'] = 1;

                $this->completeForm[$i] = $singleQuestion;
                unset($singleQuestion);
                $i++;
            }
            $_SESSION['completeForm'] = $this->completeForm; 
    }
```

I have also some js files: theory.js

```
function addStudentAnswer(id,checked,sequenceNumber,questionPosition,checkboxId){
    ris_id = id.substring(3);

    $.ajax({
        url: (URL + "teoria/addStudentAnswerAndCalculateErrorsAjax"),
        type: "POST",
        data:
            {
                ris_id: ris_id,
                checked: checked,
                sequenceNumber: sequenceNumber,
                questionPosition : questionPosition
            },
        success: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

and timer.js

```
var x = setInterval(() => {

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = time - now;
    var timeLeft = millisToMinutesAndSeconds(distance)

    if ($('#timeRemaining').length){
        document.getElementById("timeRemaining").innerHTML = timeLeft;
    }

    if (distance/1000 <= 0) {
        localStorage.removeItem('saved_countdown');
        $('#timeRemaining').css('color', 'red');
        $('#timeRemaining').html("CONCLUSO");

        location.href = URL + "teoria/saveExam";
    }
}, 1000);


function resetTimerAndSaveExam(){
    clearInterval(x);
    location.href = URL + "teoria/saveExam";

}

if($('#exerciseTipology').val() === "exam"){
    var totalMinutes = $('#totalMinutes').val();
    var time = 60 * totalMinutes; // This is the time allowed

    var saved_countdown = localStorage.getItem('saved_countdown');

    if(saved_countdown == null) {
        // Set the time we're counting down to using the time allowed
        var new_countdown = new Date().getTime() + time * 1000;
        time = new_countdown;
        localStorage.setItem('saved_countdown', new_countdown);
    } else {
        time = saved_countdown;
    }
}

function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
    var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
    return minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
}
```

Of course I have also a model file, but I don't think it's important to post it.

Comment: I think the problem was the 2 instructions in my index:
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 0);
session_set_cookie_params(0);
now it seems to work but I don't know exactly why

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime: _"session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor)."_ - by setting this to 0, you basically said that all session data is to be considered obsolete the moment it gets written, and can therefor be cleaned up by the garbage collector.